# How to add margin to listview header?

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, layoutparams

I am trying to add a `textview` to `listview` header and give left margin to it. Here is what i do:

```
//create a textview, not inflating from layout
TextView selectAdressText = new TextView(getContext());
selectAdressText.setTextSize(12);
selectAdressText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_black));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 10);
selectAdressText.setLayoutParams(lp);   

addressesLV.addHeaderView(selectAdressText);
```

But it gives `nullpointerexception`. I also tried `AbsListViewLayout` params instead of `LinearLayoutLayoutParam`s but it has no `setMargins` method. So which `LayoutParams` should i use for this?

Thanks

Comment: first addHeaderView, and AbsListView.LayoutParams set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LinearLayout header = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 10);
TextView t = new TextView(this);
header.addView(t,lp);
addressesLV.addHeaderView(header);
try it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Margin is overridden by `ListView`, so you can't use margin directly on the root view of your xml layout. Use padding instead.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"/>
```

or wrap a layout (as root node) around it:

```
<Framelayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">


   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>

</Framelayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just create your textView in xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>



View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textView, yourListview, false);
yourListview.addHeaderView(view);
```